# Adding JavaScript Chessboard Library to Angular Project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings, chessboard.js

I am trying to set up a basic angular web page that displays a chessboard. I am using the chessboardjs library found [here](https://chessboardjs.com/).

The instructions to initialize an empty chessboard as given by the website for the HTML and JS respectively are:

`<div id="board1" style="width: 400px"></div>`

`var board1 = ChessBoard('board1', 'start');`

In my typescript file, all I have so far is:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChessBoard } from 'chessboardjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
    board1 = ChessBoard('board1', 'start');
}
```

When I load my web page, I get the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

and the line it points to is where I use the ChessBoard function.

I have included the chessboard and @types/chessboard libraries through npm and have no compile errors.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated in how I can include a javascript library in my Angular project.

Answer (score 0):

**angular.json**

```
...

"scripts": [
      "call ChessBoard library here"
   ],
...
```

create new file `types.d.ts` in src directory

**types.d.ts**

```
declare const ChessBoard:any;
```

Comment: When I try pointing to the library location I get this error: 92% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:497:3)

Comment: From where are you importing the lib?

Comment: Both from node_modules. I tried the chessboardjs library and then the @types/chessboardjs library.

For example: "node_modules/chessboardjs"

Comment: Check your node_modules folder if the lib exists or not

Comment: From Where have installed the lib?

Comment: It exists. I used npm to install :/

Comment: try this if your have the same version `"node_modules/chessboardjs-0.3.0/js/chessboard-0.3.0.min.js"`

Comment: I don't have that. My version comes from: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chessboardjs

Comment: Here ist the right path for your `"node_modules/chessboardjs/www/js/chessboard.js"`

Comment: Don't forget to restart serve after changes

Comment: Okay that path worked. I now see this runtime error: chessboard.js:1703 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at chessboard.js:1703

Either way, I am much further than I was before. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you created types.d.ts fie?

Comment: Yes, how you told me. That eliminates a compile error. In app.component.ts. the error I get comes from the js file I added in my scripts section of angular.json

Answer (score 0):

AppComponent should be

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as ChessBoard from 'chessboardjs/www/js/chessboard';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  title = 'frontend';
  board1: ChessBoard;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.board1 = ChessBoard('board1', {
      draggable: true,
      pieceTheme: 'node_modules/chessboardjs/www/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png'
    });
  }

}
```

Please make sure you added jQuery in the `index.html` or `scripts` of your `angular.json` file as well as `node_modules/chessboardjs/www/css/chessboard.css` in the `stylesheets` of your `angular.json` file.